# Fancybox excessive margin

Tags: jquery, css, fancybox

Fancybox is adding excessive right margin to the overlay body.

You can see what happens here: http://www.thermae.com/boetfort/nl/fotoalbum/113/bar-restaurant

I figured it had something to do with the scrollbar (as was suggested in an earlier post around here) - but after playing around a bit this doesn't appear to be the case.

Any thoughts?

I didn't overwrite the base CSS, nor use any custom Fancybox settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you have changed to fancyBox v1, but I`ll answer anyway.

You have added extra scrolling for "html" tag:

```
html {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

And, unfortunately, that causes this issue - https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/issues/340

Comment: Yeah I switched back, to no avail. Removing the overflow-y property was the first thing I tried, but doesn't help either, I'm at a loss!

Comment: Switched to Fancybox 2 and got it working now - thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I have looked into this found that there is a problom in this css rule so just change it to

```
#fancybox-outer {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    width: 94%;
}
```

in

```
"http://www.thermae.com/js/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css"
```